# Цикл whle с двойным условием

Tags: python, python-3.x

Доброго времени суток. Изучаю python и столкнулся с проблемой: не могу понять, почему код не работает должным образом.

> Программа должна считывать размеры команд (два положительных целых
>   числа a и b, каждое число вводится на отдельной строке) и выводить
>   наименьшее число i, которое делится на оба этих числа без остатка.

Код программы, которую я написал:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
i=min(a,b)
while i%a!=0 and i%b!=0:
    i+=1
print (i)
```

Например, если ввести цифры `7` и `5`, то результат должен быть `35`. А имеем `5`. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5%7 = 5 (не равно нулю), а 5%5 = 0. Цикл будет продолжаться, пока первое выражение не равно нулю (выполняется) И(!!!) второе выражение не равно нулю (не выполняется). Истина И ложь = ложь, короче. Вам нужно не И, а ИЛИ.

Comment: Если a=7, b=5, i=5, то в while при первой интерации результат проверки условия False and True. Они ведь не совпадают, а значит цикл не должен завершиться....

Comment: @n.osennij цикл будет работать пока условие истинно, False and True дадут False, условие стало ложью.

Comment: Я понял! Гениально))) Спасибо большое!

Comment: @n.osennij Обращайтесь :-D Рекомендую почитать про булевы функции и их таблицы истинности.